# Calling function in template: send parameters with assoc. array instead of argument/value pairs

Tags: php, smarty

With Smarty 3.0, I would like to do, in order to avoid code repetition:

```
{$assocArray = ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2', ...]}
{magicFunction name='someHelper' params=$assocArray}
```

instead of

```
{$assocArray = ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2', ...]}
{someHelper param1=$assocArray['value1'] param2=$assocArray['value2'] ...}
```

I've found [`{call}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.call.tpl) but is not exactly what I'm looking for.

I will try to do it myself, but I'm open to suggestions (or even a code snippet to copy/paste :-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a wrapper function named `unroll_parameters` defined as below.

```
function unroll_params ($params, &$smarty) {
   return call_user_func_array ($params['name'], $params['args']);
}
```

That will make you able to use the following:

```
{unroll_params name='someFunction' args=$assocArray}
```

---

If you'd like to access `$smarty` inside the called function, append the value to `$params['args']` before calling `call_user_func_array`.

```
return call_user_func_array (
  $params['name'], array_merge ($params['args'], array ($smarty))
);
```

*Note: If the function declaration is like: `function foo ($var1,$var2, ..., $smarty)`*

Comment: Just for information, I've ended up with something like `return call_user_func_array ($params['name'], array($params['args'], $smarty));`. Thanks for your great answer.

Comment: @FrostyZ That be equivalent to `func (array (1,2),3)` when `$params['args] = array(1,2)` and `$smart = 3;`, is that really what you are looking for?

Comment: Since the functions I want to call through `unroll_params()` have a `function myFunction($params, &$smarty) {...}` signature, passing `array($params['args'], $smarty)` as second argument of `call_user_func_array()` is appropriate in my case (+ tested).